# trigger call_command('syncdb', all=True) from a custom management command

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-south, django-manage.py

I am trying to add standard django permissions by using `django.core.management.call_command`

When I type it in the console everything works fine, i.e.

```
$./manage.py syncdb --all
```

This creates all permissions for existing django models (even for those with added south migrations).

Now I want to use it in a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/), so I implemented it like this:

In the body of the `handle(*args, **kwargs)` method, after I import the method `from django.core.management import call_command` I added the following:

```
call_command('syncdb', all=True)
```

This call creates permission instances for some of the models, but all with migrations are passed over. How can I force it to create all permissions for all models?

Comment: I cleaned up your question; hopefully it still describes your problem.

Comment: Which version of django?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.6.5

Comment: did you ever figure it out?